# Is it possible to use separate DB for slow_backend cache?

Tags: database, cache, backend

I've tried the following local.xml conf without any luck:

```
<resources>
    <cache_db>
        <connection>
            <host><![CDATA[]]></host>
            <username><![CDATA[]]></username>
            <password><![CDATA[]]></password>
            <dbname><![CDATA[]]></dbname>
            <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
            <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
            <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
            <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
            <active>1</active>
        </connection>
    </cache_db>
</resources>
<cache>
    <slow_backend>database</slow_backend>
    <slow_backend_options>
        <connection>cache_db</connection>
    </slow_backend_options>
</cache>
```

I even tried defining connection directly in slow_backend_options like this:

```
<cache>
    <slow_backend>database</slow_backend>
    <slow_backend_options>
        <connection>
            <host><![CDATA[]]></host>
            <username><![CDATA[]]></username>
            <password><![CDATA[]]></password>
            <dbname><![CDATA[]]></dbname>
            <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
            <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
            <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
            <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
            <active>1</active>
        </connection>
    </slow_backend_options>
</cache>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, What you are trying to do ..?

Comment: check this http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/magento-caching-internals.html , see if it helpess!

Comment: Trying to use a second DB connection as a slow_backend for the two level cache.  All cache read/writes would go to this second DB connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are currently on EE 1.12 and it turns out that this is a new feature in CE 1.8 and EE 1.13.  Magento support was able to provide a back-port patch for EE 1.12.  Users on CE might be able to simply put the CE 1.8 Mage_Core_Model_Cache file in their local, but I would recommend upgrading the whole installation instead.

Answer (score 1):

This should work as long as you enable to level cache. You can do this by adding the following to your config.

```
<cache>
    <backend_options>
        <enable_two_levels>true</enable_two_levels> <!-- Enable two level cache -->
```

When this is activated then the following function call happens.

```
if ($enable2levels) {
    $backendOptions = $this->_getTwoLevelsBackendOptions($backendOptions, $cacheOptions);
}
```

This will then get the backend options using `$options['slow_backend_options'] = $this->getDbAdapterOptions($options['slow_backend_options']);` which uses the `connection` node under the `slow_backend_options` node.